# How to select 5.5 or 7 pt font in mtpro2?

Tags: fonts, fontsize, mtpro

The 7 pt and 5.5 pt fonts are for sub/superscripts and second-order sub/superscripts respectively. I am trying to use them as part of the body text. Comparison with [this mtpro2 brochure](https://www.pctex.com/files/managed/5/52/MTP2flyerFontList.pdf) shows that my attempt doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[subscriptcorrection,slantedGreek,nofontinfo,amsbb,eucal]{mtpro2}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
{\fontsize{5.5}{5.5}\selectfont\bfseries GH}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `mtpro` provides math-mode fonts. Your example works with a text-mode font.

Answer (score 2):

You loaded `fontspec` and set your main font to Times New Roman, so you’re scaling that and not your Math Time Pro fonts.

You almost certainly want to use `\small`, `\footnotesize`, `\scriptsize`  or `\tiny` with a scalable font, here.  Any of these should select the correct optical size.  The setting that should match the size of your math scripts is probably `\scriptsize`, and the setting that should match your sub-sub-scripts or super-super-scripts is probably `\tiny`.  I know that TeX Gyre Termes does have more than one optical size, but I don’t have `mtpro2` to test.